# Hyperbolic groups and cohomology

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, geometric-group-theory

I'm looking for a reference (survey article, monograph, etc.) that treats the cohomological properties of hyperbolic groups and/or its generalizations as relatively hyperbolic groups, lacunary hyperbolic groups or acylindrically hyperbolic groups.

Comment: A silly observation: for any group $G$, the free product $G \ast \mathbb{F}_n$ is a relatively hyperbolic group (and a fortiori an acylindrically hyperbolic group). Because the cohomological groups of $G \ast \mathbb{F}_n$ are essentially the sames as those of $G$, it seems that there are no restrictions on the possible cohomological groups of a relatively (or acylindrically) hyperbolic group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a few original papers as opposed to surveys/monographs, let me suggest two papers, the first on $L_\infty$ homology and the second on bounded cohomology:

- Allcock, D. J.; Gersten, S. M.
  A homological characterization of hyperbolic groups.
  Invent. Math. 135 (1999), no. 3, 723–742
- Mineyev, Igor.
  Bounded cohomology characterizes hyperbolic groups.
  Q. J. Math. 53 (2002), no. 1, 59–73.

Comment: @M.U. Also: "The Boundary of Negatively Curved Groups" by Bestvina and Mess, JAMS, 1991.